# In matlab is it possible to vectorize in more than one dimension?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

The matlab documentation explains [vectorization](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html#btimcm2-3) with

> ```
> i = 0;
> for t = 0:.01:10
>     i = i + 1;
>     y(i) = sin(t);
> end
>
> This is a vectorized version of the same code:
>
> t = 0:.01:10;
> y = sin(t);
> ```

Can I apply vectorization to a function with non-scalar inputs and outputs? As a toy example, take the function `foo`

```
function out = foo(in)
  out(1) = in(1);
  out(2) = in(2);
end
```

It's just the identity. I'd like to do something like

```
inputs = [1,2; 3,4; 5,6];
t = 1:3;
outputs = foo(inputs(t,:))
```

and get

```
ans = 
     1    2
     3    4
     5    6
```

Instead I end up with

```
ans = 
     1    3
```

Clearly, I'm either doing it wrong or it's not possible. Help!

Comment: Try `out(:, 1) = in(:, 1)` and `out(:, 2) = in(:, 2)`, is that what you want?

Comment: Your example **is** one-dimensional.  You're confused because you are working with different scales.  But even for 2-dimensional arrays (which look like matrices),  if you experiment with 1-dimensional addressing you'll see it's not hard to get the desired results, as Felix' answer points out.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to vectorize in Matlab in N-dimensions. As it was mentioned by Andrew you can simply writte a function like:

```
function out = foo(in)
  out(:,1:size(in,2)) = in(:,1:size(in,2));
end
```

Output will be as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Using the (:) index operator on n-dimensional arrays allows you to perform vectorized operations on all elements. You can use e.g. reshape to put the result back into the same form as the input.

```
function out=foo(in)
         out=reshape(in(:),size(in));
```

Comment: But beware of default order.   `foo=reshape(1:6,2,3); foo2=reshape(7:12,3,2)` then look at `foo(:)+foo2(:)` vs. `foo+foo2'` vs `foo'+foo2`

Comment: That would only matter for operations on arrays of different sizes though.

Answer (score 0):

**The unexpected output**

The reason your output is `[1 3]` has to do with linear indexing of matrixes. In particular this means that you can access the full matrix with a vector, where you first count through the first column, then the second column and so on. For a `3x2` matrix this would be:

```
 1 4 
 2 5 
 3 6
```

Therefore `in(1) = 1` is the first element in the first column. `in(2) = 3` is the second element in the first column. Find the full documentation for matrix indexing [here](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html).

**The input**

Secondly writing `outputs = foo(inputs(t,:))` means that you take all rows specified in `t` with no condition to the columns. Therefore in your example it is equivalent to write `outputs = foo(inputs)` and `outputs = foo(inputs(t,:))` as you put in all 3 rows. What you could do is let `foo()` have two arguments.

```
function out = foo(t,in)
out = in(t,:)
```

To have access to the rows inside the function you could write something like:

```
function out = foo(in);

[x,y] = size(in);    
for t = 1:x
    out(t,:) = in(t,:);
end
```

Normally vectorization is used to avoid looping through scalars. There are a lot of clever ways to simplify code and reduce it's computation time. Most techniques like `.* ,.^, bsxfun()` are already presented in the documentation about [vectorization](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html#btimcm2-3) you already found. The tricky part is to find the right way to apply these methods. It takes a lot of experience and a sharp eye to fully utilize them, as in every case you need to adjust to the specific logic of your opperations.

Feel free to ask if you still struggle with your problem.